# Prometheus to get trigger an alert when node is in unschedulable state

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

Can someone help me in writing a promql query to get the node status whether node is schedulable or not. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you read up on Prometheus queries and post a more specific question?

Answer (score 7):

If you use prometheus-operator, `kube-state-metrics` return `kube_node_status_condition` metric:

```
sum(kube_node_status_condition{condition="Ready",status!="true"})
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer would show if a node it ready or not - a node can be ready but unschedulable (an example would be if you cordoned a node with:

```
kubectl cordon NODE)
```

Below example should cover a ready node that is unschedulable and is also available via `kube-state-metrics`

```
sum(kube_node_spec_unschedulable) by (node)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm referencing the `machine_cpu_cores` metric. It will only show nodes that are ready in a Kubernetes cluster.